# Can anyone tell me the meaning of this word "cool" in these sentences?

Tags: meaning

> "I know you don't like me back. It's cool."

Comment: This site strives to provide well researched, intriguing questions. Take the [site tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) or have a look at the [help center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help) to find out more about good questions. You might find your question fitting better in at our sister site for [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: It means, _it's okay._

Comment: [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/) is the place to go for definitions of slang terms.

Answer (score 1):

> Acceptable; satisfactory: *It's cool if you don't want to talk about
>   it.*

https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=cool